# What is the best way to view and rotate images from a camera on a mac?

Tags: macos, image-viewer

I need a good image viewer and image rotator for a mac. What is the best light weight tool for this?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Download Picasa 3.6 for Mac](http://picasa.google.com/mac/). This is an excellent software.

Comment: Yup I just starting using it on my mac, works like a charm!

Comment: Indeed. It's a great software

Answer (score 1):

Preview (built in app from Apple) does the job too...